# Обработка прикосновений на всей Layout, включая детей (таких как button и пр.)

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener

Имеется Activity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // this is the view on which you will listen for touch events
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.ll);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " + String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_weight="0.50" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_weight="0.50" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, TestActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Как обрабатывать касание (в данном случае показать координаты), также и на кнопке `@+id/button` ?

Comment: Задайте setOnTouchListener для вашего layout

Comment: А я что сделал ?

Comment: Не посмотрел Ваш код и сразу ответил на вопрос в заголовке. Переформулируйте тогда. Попробуйте разделить  button и корневой layout. Таким образом у вас будет: корневой layout, button и ещё один layout с остальным контентом. Так вы сможете разделить логику по раздельному нажатию на layout и button.

Comment: не хочу я ничего разделять :) Это тестовый layout специально созданный для данного вопроса и никак иначе, с целью получения конкретного ответа...